# nestjs build error for dev-dependency module ts-loader

Tags: typescript, docker, nestjs, npm-build

I'm getting following `Module Error` for `ts-loader` while `docker build`

```
ERROR [6/6] RUN nest build                                                                                                                                3.9s
------
 > [6/6] RUN nest build:
#10 3.863 ERROR in main
#10 3.863 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in '/user/src/app'
#10 3.863 resolve 'ts-loader' in '/user/src/app'
#10 3.863   Parsed request is a module
#10 3.863   using description file: /user/src/app/package.json (relative path: .)
#10 3.863     resolve as module
#10 3.863       looking for modules in /user/src/app/node_modules
#10 3.863         single file module
#10 3.863           using description file: /user/src/app/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/ts-loader)
#10 3.863             no extension
#10 3.863               /user/src/app/node_modules/ts-loader doesn't exist
#10 3.863             .js
#10 3.863               /user/src/app/node_modules/ts-loader.js doesn't exist
#10 3.863         /user/src/app/node_modules/ts-loader doesn't exist
#10 3.863       /user/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
#10 3.863       /user/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
#10 3.863       /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
#10 3.863
#10 3.863 webpack 5.73.0 compiled with 1 error in 2169 ms
```

Following is the `Dockerfile` I'm using

```
FROM node:18-alpine

ENV TEST_ENV=docker_baap
ENV PORT=3500
WORKDIR /user/src/app
 
COPY . .
RUN npm i -g @nestjs/cli@9.0.0
RUN npm ci --omit=dev
 
RUN nest build
 
USER node
 
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

the error is caused due to `npm ci --omit=dev` but how can it be resolved for production environment?

Comment: here's a Dockerfile that I've been using for production: https://gist.github.com/micalevisk/9ee47135b22f284dd73de6ea6d5aa864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dev dependencies to build the application, but not to run it.

You can do a multistage docker build.

In the first stage you install all dependencies and build the application.

In the second stage, you only install production dependencies and copy built application(`/dist`) from first stage.